# Are my ripples gone?

Tags: ripple

Long time ago I registered on ripple.com and had some ripples there. I still remember my login/password but the site is completely different now and it looks like there is no option to log-in anymore.

Is there any hope to log-in to my old account and get my ripples?

*Few other details to not confuse people who try to help by answering my question:* I am pretty sure it was a ripple.com (I use lastpass which stores information about the site/login/password). I have not bought XRP, I got them for free (as far as I remember in the very early days they were giving ~100 or so to people just to try it).

Comment: How long ago was this?

Comment: @PieterWuille this I do not remember. I assume that it was before 2014, because this is when I stopped checking various cryptos.

Comment: Actually I remember a few years back they handed out some ripple on ripple.com. Then I *think* they changed to rippletrade.com (?) or something, now I think this is closed too.

Comment: @DanielMorritt this is exactly what happened. Thank you for rippletrade.com. Will check whether this is something real.

Comment: If you used ripple trade, you can retrieve your secret key [here](https://id.ripple.com/auth/migrate) or you can migrate to a GateHub wallet.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my problem @DavidSchwartz. Sadly I never used ripple trade (at the time I received ripples there was no such thing). The only thing I have is the login/password to a ripple.com site where my ripples were 3-4 years ago.

Comment: @looking_for_ripples That was likely the original Ripple client. I believe its accounts were migrated to ripple trade automatically. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I@DavidSchwartz I see that there I need to provide a country/email address which I do not remember providing when I used ripple.com. Will try to do this tomorrow. By the way do you know why does ripple need so much PII data? I am really glad that one of the top guys in ripple helped me :-)

Comment: I have had the same experience.  It seems https://id.ripple.com/auth/migrate is the place now.  But how can I trust it?  They want me to type in my private key?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could check waybackmachine? I've searched a bit on there and can't seem to find a login page somewhere on the website in 2014/2015.

Altho it's crazy how often Ripple updated their complete layout.
Almost every year they have a new design.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150204002201/https://ripple.com/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you were on "ripple.com" and not another phising website trying to get your money and scam you. To my knowledge Ripple never sold XRP coins directly through their website.

People reported "fake" websites for ripple in the near past ... (saw it through several twitter channels. I guess you got scammed : /

Comment: I am pretty sure it was a ripple.com (I use lastpass which stores information about the site/login/password). I have not bought XRP, I got them for free (as far as I remember in the very early days they were giving ~100 or so to people just to try it).

Added this to my question